# Divide Legend by multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

In am looking a solution to a different representation of the legend to the example given here:
https://rpubs.com/ageek/ggplot-adv-part2

The code below gives the following graph:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(manufacturer))+
    geom_bar(aes(fill=class), width = 0.5)+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6))
```

[image: Image_Example]

Is there a way to represent the legend in groups for each different value of the variable x (discrete) given in x axis? For example, in the above example the legend for the first two entries in the x axis (Audi and Chevrolet) would look as following:

[image: Image_DesiredOutcome]

In the desired outcome, all entries in x axis should be included in the legend, and dynamically change in case the legend is adjusted (e.g. Audi removed or a new brand is added)

Comment: So you want 15 different groups in the legend? Then your legend would be larger than your plot and very difficult to read. If you want to clearly label what each bar represents, it would look better (and be far easier) to directly label the bars.

Comment: What is the maximum number of classes per x value? And how many x values? It would be possible to have legend keys under each x axis tick, provided there were not too many x axis ticks or classes per x value

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, exactly 15 different groups in the legend. I can make them smaller or stack them in order to fit if needed. Unfortunately, in my real example I have more than 50 classes that stack and repeat through each different value in x-axis. Therefore, labels inside each bar for each stacked class would look messy. Another solution is to post them in a new plot below the graph. But still I am not sure how can create all new grouped legends, store them and then plot them in a new plot.

Comment: I could show you how to do that but could you answer the questions in my other comment?

Comment: The maximum number of classes per x is actually variable and can diverge from an entry to the next. E.g. it can be 50 classes per x entry or just 1. My x axis is actually the years, with starting year from 2008 until current year 2022, so at the moment 14, but its extended each year.

Comment: A legend with 50 different discrete classes is just useless for a plot. No one will be able to read or interpret it. I think you need to reconsider how you are going to present your data.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance so far. Some help to the actual question of the example above with the 7 classes and the 15 groups(x-axis entries) would be more than enough for me. Whether the final data displayed in the graph will be readable or not I believe its something that it is not a part of my question as the question focuses only on dynamically dividing the legend to groups based on x-axis

Comment: Sure - the problem is that this is difficult to achieve in ggplot and would require a lot of effort. You might struggle to get anyone to put that effort in when the end result will inevitably be a mess. Hopefully I'm wrong about that. Good luck!

Comment: there is some guide_merge function in ggplot2 but unfortunately it seems its not ready to use yet... I would love a simple solution to merge/aggregate legend guides in ggplot

Answer (score 1):

This is not too difficult with a mix of patchwork and cowplot. My answer is just to show the technical feasibility - I do not endorse this type of visualisation and I totally agree with Allan. To consider: You present the manufacturer/class relation already in the main plot - Your legend design would duplicate this!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(patchwork)

## named vector so you get the correct color mapping
class_colors <- setNames(scales::hue_pal()(length(unique(mpg$class))), sort(unique(mpg$class)))

p <-
  ggplot(mpg, aes(manufacturer)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = class), width = 0.5) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, vjust = 0.6),
    ## remove legend
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  ## for better control use the same colors in the main plot
  scale_fill_manual(values = class_colors)

## split by your categorising variable and loop a plot over it
ls_man <- mpg %>%
  split(.$manufacturer)

## I'm looping over an index so I can dynamically change legend title and breaks
ls_plots <- lapply(1:length(ls_man), function(i) {
  ggplot(ls_man[[i]], aes(manufacturer)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = class), width = 0.5) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, vjust = 0.6)) +
    labs(fill = names(ls_man)[i]) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = class_colors, breaks = unique(ls_man[[i]]$class))
})
## create the legends with patchwork and cowplot
p_mess <- wrap_plots(ls_plots) + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
p_leg <- get_legend(p_mess)

## draw the final plot with cowplot
ggdraw(plot_grid(p, p_leg))
```

The legends are all there, but it's just so messy you cannot see them because of the small size of this device.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! 
Would there be maybe an option to store legends in a e.g. list and print them below the graph in a new wrapped in a graph(e.g. with columns =n  - to be the legend classes) which contains just the legends?
I guess then it will be clearer representation of the classes contained for each item in x axis.

Comment: @KosKokk I would really recommend not to pursue that visualisation. This was merely to demonstrate technical feasibility. Any effort put into further design is rather futile. If you want others to give it a shot, I'd advise to ask a follow up question - please then also link to this thread

Comment: Thank you again for the time spent. I fully understand that the graph will not be fully clear, but this is what I need for my current task. I will post a workaround if I find any.